# Amazon instance stop start again

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

After I stopped my intance and started it again I am not able to open my website ,
Ip address has been changed and will stopping my instance will remove all the data?
I am using aws (amazone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you stop and start the instance, AWS allocates a new public IP. You can use an [Elastic IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) address and assign it to your instance so that the IP address won't change.

Comment: ty it helped me !